# How to get those customer only who has products in wishlist?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using following code to get the customers who are having products in their wishlist

```
 $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist')->getCollection();    

$wishlistCustomers = array();
foreach($wishlist as $wish)
{   
    $wishlistCustomers[] = $wish->getCustomerId();  
}
print_r($wishlistCustomers);
```

But it is also giving me the customers who does no have products in the wishlist.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getItemsCount()` method of the `wishlist` model to check if a wishlist has any items in it.

```
...

foreach($wishlist as $wish)
{                   
    if($wish->getItemsCount() > 0){
        $wishlistCustomers[] = $wish->getCustomerId();  
    }
}
print_r($wishlistCustomers);
```